# ReCaptcha isn't displaying (or taking up space) in chrome.

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, recaptcha

So, I have a recaptcha widget added to forms within a site I'm working on. I'm using the widget on several different pages, but am only having the problem on one of them. I am only having this problem in chrome.

When the page is first loaded, the widget doesn't appear at all. And I don't mean just the image; I mean the whole widget! It acts as if "display:none" was applied to it as it's not taking up any space and none of its elements (even those which are literally written into the html) are visible.

It consistently appears when I mouseover a submit button after it. Once the widget has appeared, it stays put and doesn't flicker or anything. It will also magically appear if I change ANY of the styles for any of the elements in chrome's web inspector.

The crazy thing is that I looked through every element of the widget and there are not any styles relating to it that would cause nothing to take up space. It totally blows my mind.

So, hopefully this is something people know about. I'll post code, but I don't know how useful it will be out of context.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="recaptcha-widget" style="display:none">
    <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
    <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol"
         style="color:red">Oops! Please try again.
    </div>
    <div class="recaptcha_links">
        <div class="recaptcha_refreshbox"><a
            href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()"
            title="Get another CAPTCHA"></a></div>
        <div class="recaptcha_only_if_image">
            <a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio');$('#recaptcha_response_field').attr('placeholder', 'Enter the numbers you hear:')" title="Get an audio CAPTCHA"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">
            <a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image');$('#recaptcha_response_field').attr('placeholder', 'Type the two words above:')" title="Get an image CAPTCHA"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="recaptcha_help">
            <a href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()" title="Help"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" placeholder="Type the two words above:"/>
    <span class="recaptcha_credit">reCAPTCHA</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfMxd4SAAAAAAqJZtKSb2Z4ilabUaMZiTyBGpGu">
</script>
<noscript>
    <iframe
        src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfMxd4SAAAAAAqJZtKSb2Z4ilabUaMZiTyBGpGu"
        height="300" width="500"
        frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <br>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #recaptcha-widget {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #40403E;
    padding: 8px 8px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

#recaptcha_image {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#recaptcha_image img {
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#recaptcha_response_field {
    width: 282px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    background-image: none;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

form.on-white #recaptcha_response_field
{
    color: white;
}

#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 95px;
    height: 57px;
}

#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #595957;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}

#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links div.recaptcha_refreshbox {
    width: 50px;
    height: 57px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links .recaptcha_only_if_audio,
#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links .recaptcha_only_if_image {
    top: 0;
    left: 55px;
}

#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_credit {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #666;
}

#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links .recaptcha_help {
    top: 32px;
    left: 55px;
}

#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links a {
    background-image: url('../images/recaptcha-sprite.png');
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;

}

#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links .recaptcha_refreshbox a {
    width: 32px;
    height: 37px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    margin-top: 9px;
}

#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links .recaptcha_only_if_image a {
    width: 19px;
    height: 17px;
    background-position: -48px -20px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links .recaptcha_only_if_audio a {
    width: 28px;
    height: 13px;
    background-position: -36px -3px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links .recaptcha_help a {
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    background-position: -35px -21px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}

/* #central-box is an ancestor of the problem child */

#central-box #recaptcha-widget
{
    width: 330px;
    position: relative;
}

#central-box #recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links
{
    float: right;
}

#central-box #recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links+div
{
    float: left;
}

#central-box #recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links+div span
{
    display:block;
    text-align: right;
}

#central-box #recaptcha-widget .recaptcha_links+div input
{
    width: 210px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var RecaptchaOptions = {
theme: 'custom',
custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha-widget'
},
RecaptchaInput = $('#recaptcha_response_field');
```

Comment: Perhaps your code is affected by changes made on Google api recently (end of summer)?

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none">

<div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
<div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">' . $strincorrectpleasetryagain . '</div>


</br></br>
```

The Above Break down to the div will work. I have done it to my site by place the Line Break only then it started working on Crome and IE.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: No way to understand the meaning and purpose of your answer. Moreover your first div is even not closed...